# "Get Started" button doesn't work on careers.stackexchange site

Tags: bug, jobs

I am trying to register my account on careers.stackexchange.com, but when I fill in all fields on the "Fill out your profile" and I click "Get Started", it fails with no error message (it stays on the same screen). Tried with IE and Chrome: same thing.

Is it a test I have to pass to get hired? ;)